# Read_Fwf drops leading zeros off of one file but not the other?

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading in 2 .dat files into a pandas dataframe using read_fwf and a list of column dividers. The last column in my dataframe drops the leading zeros (what I want) in one scenario but not the other.

[File 1 (Bad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvKK1.png)

[File 2 (Good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXEHG.png)

Below is the code I have written to load each file:

```
fhand=open(r'xyz')
divider=[(0,10),(11,15),(15,24),(24,35),(35,57),(61,75),(72,99)]

df=pd.read_fwf(fhand,colspecs=divider)
df.columns= ['Date','FundID','ID','Ticker','SecName','Quantity','Other']
df.pop('Date')
df.pop('Other')
```

This is a line of each file source where I have highlighted what is being read into the quantity column.
[File 1 Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjzMC.png)
[File 2 Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfYTy.png)

[TexttoCols in Excel is correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqcNt.png)

Comment: I will add that the "Bad File" is somehow dropping the leading zeros off of the first piece (in the sample data 000000009075 is changing to just 9075) correctly but not in the last column

Comment: When I do text to columns in excel it also appears to fit correctly

Comment: Update: I believe it is because File 2 is reading in as type String while File 1 is reading in as numpy int64). Any thoughts on why this might be?